# Visual Studio for Mac is getting error 62 - XamlCTask failed unexpectedly

Tags: xamarin, build

I am still getting the XamlCTask error 62 for one of my projects.  The error message does not give me information as to how to resolve the error.

I have installed the latest version of VS for Mac.

Any assistance is appreciated.

Thanks, Allen

Comment: What version of Xamarin Forms are you using? You need to use a pretty up to date version with VS for Mac, so try updating to the latest and see if that fixes it.

Comment: I have updated both Xamarin and Forms to the latest version.  Updating fixed 5 of my apps, but this one still won't compile.